# Pelican on S3: theme not rendering properly

Tags: css, amazon-s3, favicon, pelican

I've installed Pelican in a virtual environment following the instructions in http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.5.0/quickstart.html#installation . Running `make html` and then `make serve` does produce the expected result on `localhost:8000`: content and theme are rendered as expected. There is a warning from the local server however:

`WARNING:root:Unable to find file /favicon.ico/index.html or variations.`

I run `make s3_upload` with and without the `--guess-mime-type` option. In either case I make sure the `css` files in my s3 bucket <s>have the right mime type (text/plain)</s>  **CSS files must have text/css as mime-type**:

```
 Done: Processed 1 article(s), 0 draft(s) and 0 page(s) in 0.35 seconds.
 s3cmd sync /home/theuser/virtualenvs/pelican/theblog/output/ s3://theuser.com --acl-public --delete-removed --guess-mime-type
```

Files do upload to s3 but the blog isn't rendered properly (apparently the css directives aren't recognized). I did not add any inline css in my test markdown document.

Why isn't the blog rendering properly from s3? Where should I be looking for error logs? Thanks.

EDIT:

I ran the blog through http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ , and got "Congratulation, no error found" & "This document validates as CSS level 3".

Assuming the blog's URI is `www.theuser.com`, I've also tried setting `pelicanconf.py`'s `SITEURL` as

```
 SITEURL =  'http://s3.amazonaws.com/theuser.com'
 SITEURL =  'http://theuser.com'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what else I broke fixing the problem above, but removing `python-magic` did the trick.

Apparently `python-magic` wasn't allowing the right mime-types to be set by `s3cmd`, particularly for CSS files: their mime type defaulted to `text/plain`. CSS mime-type must be set to `text/css` on S3 or the CSS files will be disregarded.

This link put me on the right track: http://worklog.kevinclarke.info/2014/08/28/fixing-css-mime-type-for-s3-octopress/